# Simple Java Concurrency Issue

Tags: java, concurrency

I have a class that extends JPanel and draws ~10 images on screen by overriding the paint method (using this method as I want to be able to manipulate the images as I draw each one). What I want to be able to do is have an update method in the class which I pass a list of potential image updates every frame. Here is what I have

```
List<BufferedImage> imageList = Collections.synchronizedList(new ArrayList());

public void update(list<String> imagePaths) {
    for (String path : imagePaths) {
        synchronized (imageList) {
            //Modify image list adding and removing buffered images
        }
    }
    repaint();
}

@Override
public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
     synchronized (imageList) {
         g.drawImage(img, 0, 0, this);
     }
}
```

Currently as you can imagine it runs extremely slow due to the synchronized blocks? How can I drastically improve the performance please?

Comment: Don't paint in a sync'd block - just take a snapshot of the list at the start of the method and use that.

Answer (score 1):

You're using a synchronized list, and then also synchronizing **on** that list when you iterate it. You'll probably see better performance by using something like a `CopyOnWriteArrayList`, which will always provide a consistent snapshot when iterated, and remove the synchronized blocks entirely.

Although, looking at your snippet, it's not clear to me which list is being iterated -- you have `imageList` and `imagePaths`, and I'm not sure where the actual images are retrieved from the list.